# How to check if page has status published

Tags: select, post-status

How to check if page `id(SomeID)` is actually published?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `'publish' === get_post_status( $id )`, where `$id` could be the current page ID retrieved via `get_the_ID()` or any other.

Comment: @kaiser It's not really explicit that it's the current page he wants to check. At least that's not how I interpreted the question.

Comment: You're right. I'll fix it. Just wanted to get it out of the review row - too short answers are flagged by the community user.

Comment: Yeah I've noticed that several times. It's annoying when people forget to add back-ticks around php tags. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
<?php
  $page_id = 20; // example id of your page 
  $page = get_page( $page_id );
  if ($page->post_status == 'publish') {
    // page is published

  }
?>
```

Comment: This example is the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

You must retrieve the page via the function [get_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page).

Look for the `post_status` field in the returned object!